# Implementing R's geom_count() using only matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, ggplot2

R has a very nice plotting function called [`geom_count`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_count.html) that very flexibly displays frequency/categorical data. I believe [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/categorical.html) also has great many options for such kind of plots but nothing exactly matching the `geom_counts` feature where the size of the scatter plot points is determined by the number of occurrences.

I wanted to stick to `matplotlib` only (and also not have to use dataframes from `pandas` for a simple list of lists) so I made the following minimal example/implementation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import randint, choices
from collections import Counter
import string

base_list = list(string.ascii_uppercase[0:11])
newlist, count_dict = list(), dict()

for item in base_list:
    newlist.append(choices(base_list, k=80))

for letter, item in zip(base_list,newlist):
    count_dict[letter] = Counter(item)

plt.figure()
for x, xpos in enumerate(base_list):
    for y, ypos  in enumerate(base_list):
        plt.scatter(x+1, y+1, s=count_dict[xpos][ypos]*20, c='b')
plt.show()
```

I am unhappy with this for couple of reasons:

1. The multiple calls to `plt.scatter` to plot each point is painful and slow for larger data sets.
2. The two explicit `for` loops seem very un-pythonic to me (and in the above case only works because the number of items in `base_list` is the same as that of in `newlist`).

I can probably generalize to having different number of items in `base_list` and `newlist` (see last figures in the link to [`geom_count`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_count.html)) ...

... but before I proceed I wanted to ask if someone has come across a similar question/problem/code that implements the frequency of occurrence based scatter plot sizing using **only `matplotlib`** ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import randint, choices
from collections import Counter
import string
import numpy as np
from operator import itemgetter

base_list = list(string.ascii_uppercase[0:11])
newlist, count_dict = list(), dict()

for item in base_list:
    newlist.append(choices(base_list, k=80))

for letter, item in zip(base_list,newlist):
    count_dict[letter] = Counter(item)


z=np.array([itemgetter(*base_list)(_temp) for _temp in itemgetter(*base_list)(count_dict)])
x,y=np.meshgrid(np.arange(len(base_list)),np.arange(len(base_list))) 
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x+1,y+1,s=z*20,c='b')
plt.show()
```